# Bukkit conversation fails sleeping

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to use a Bukkit conversation, which already works, yet, when I use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(integer-value)`, it works once, and then it fails with this error in console: `java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted`

When a prompt has been shown and the next is going to be shown the method *acceptInput* is called. In the first prompt it works all fine, in the other prompts, which are called out of this prompt (the prompt calls a new instance of itself). All works fine except the sleep part. Any ideas to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
package dbx12.Test1.Tutorial.Prompts;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.bukkit.conversations.ConversationContext;
import org.bukkit.conversations.Prompt;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;


public class Text implements Prompt {

    @Override
    public Prompt acceptInput(ConversationContext context, String input) {
        int thisPrompt = (int) context.getSessionData("step");
        context.setSessionData("step", thisPrompt+1);
        Player p = (Player) context.getForWhom();

        boolean type;

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(dbx12.Test1.Utils.Prompt_List.delay.get(thisPrompt));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace(); //DEBUG
        }       

        try {
            type = dbx12.Test1.Utils.Prompt_List.promptType.get(thisPrompt+1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Finish();
        }

        if(dbx12.Test1.Utils.Prompt_List.hasLocation.get(thisPrompt+1) == true)
            p.teleport(dbx12.Test1.Utils.Prompt_List.location.get(thisPrompt+1));

        if(type==true)
        {
            System.out.println("return a text");
            return new Text();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("return a interaction");
            return new Interaction();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean blocksForInput(ConversationContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPromptText(ConversationContext context) {
        return dbx12.Test1.Utils.Prompt_List.promptText.get(context.getSessionData("step"));
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Set a delay? What is this plugin going to be doing? There may be a better way of doing this.

Comment: I try to show information via prompts. After a certain delay the next prompt is shown. The delay works at the first time, but fails in the next x prompts. I call the next prompt as new instance of this one.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` will cause your entire server to stop doing anything for x seconds. Instead of sleep, use a `SyncDelayedTask`:

```
this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //what you want to do here
    }
},delayInSeconds * 20);
```

so, lets say for example you wanted to send `test1` to the server, then `test2` to the server 5 seconds later, you could use:

```
int repeats;

public void sendMessages(){
    this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
        if(repeats == 0){ //if it's the first time running
            Bukkit.getServer.broadcastMessage("test1");
            repeats++; //add to repeats
            sendMessages(); //call the method again
        }
        else if(repeats == 1){ //if it is the second time being called
            Bukkit.getServer.broadcastMessage("test2");
        }
    }
},5 * 20);//wait 5 seconds
```

so with the above code, you could make a method like this:

```
public void startSendingMessages(){
    repeats = 0;
    sendMessages();
}
```

Where when you called `startSendingMessages()`, the `test1` would be sent, then, 5 seconds later, `test2` would be sent.

The reason we are multiplying the time in seconds by 20, is because it has to be in ticks, or minecraft time, and `1 second = 20 ticks`.

There's lots of other scheduler types, like `SyncRepeatingTasks`. To learn more about them, check out the bukkit `JavaDocs`: http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/, theres also a nice tutorial from bukkit here: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming

Comment: This won't work in they way I want. Maybe I wasn't precise enough ;)
I want to delay the execution at the point where I used the
`try{            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(dbx12.Test1.Utils.Prompt_List.delay.get(thisPrompt));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace(); //DEBUG
        } `
So I try to wait until a specified time is over and then I want to return a new "Finish" or "Text" or "Interaction". At the time I return a Prompt this Prompt is shown. So I want to delay the display of this Prompt.

Comment: Sorry for the bad format but stackoverflow cancelled my edits because I went over 5 minutes. Off-topic: A preview or longer time for editing would be nice.

Comment: @DBX12 same principle applies, you could just change the time at the bottom, here: `},5 * 20);` to `the time you want * 20`